# AFNetworking POST non JSON String

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to create a POST request by using `AFNetworking` library.

```
[self.manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response)
{
    // CODE
}

failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    // CODE
}];
```

Is there a way to post a simple string (not a JSON one) as a request body parameters by using `AFNetworking`?

Comment: parameters contains key and value , how do u need

Comment: I need parameters to be a simple string like `@"This is a string"`, but not a JSON like `{"message":"This is a string"}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is how you do it:

```
NSString *someString = @"SomeString";
NSData* stringData = [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someUrlString"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy  timeoutInterval:20];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: stringData  ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   //Success Block
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure Block
}];
[op start];
```